# Rounded Semicircle with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm struggling to make the semicircle edges round, where can i fix my code?

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 70;
  left: 20;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
  border: 20px solid #fff58f;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and share all the html and css code? Only this much code won't help

Comment: You will most likely need to use a canvas element, an image or do some complicated CSS transformations. Using a canvas element you can draw a line with rounded points, doing this without a canvas element is possible with *more elements (*or psuedo selectors) which can make it more complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility with css

I have used `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements for the rounded corner for the semi circle.

```css
.parentcircle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #824b20;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.outercircle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e08027;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 100%;
  border: 20px solid #FFF58F;
  border-top: 0
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF58F;
  top: -10px;
  left: -20px;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF58F;
  top: -10px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentcircle">
  <div class="outercircle">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not showing rounded corners.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer and not "another possibility with CSS" though..

Comment: Defenitely its an another implementation. Your solution makes use of hardcorded dimention value for all of its elements. I have made that dimention dependency to a minimal level. Also both of our answers have the same way of implementation, but with different approach. Also I was not aware what you have posted as the solution while I was submitting the answer. I have developed my own solution for this one

Comment: I'm not being offensive or anything but it is a duplicate, no matter if you accept it or not. OP was asking for a way to make the corners of a border rounded, which I answered is possible with pseudo elements. Then you answered with "Another possibility with CSS" meaning that you indeed saw the other answer. As for the "hardcoded dimensions", it is out of OP's question scope. OP did not mention anything about responsiveness, he just wanted a path to follow.

Comment: I was focusing on providing the css solution the OP was intersted in, not just the rounded corner. Also there is no other simpler way to create a rounded corner than using before and after pseudo elements. And my description to the answer `"Another possibility with CSS"` only means that you have already posted an anser and this can be done in this manner too. Its my solution and my way of implementation. "OP did not mention anything about responsiveness", but I took that into consideration while delveloping the answer. My ansers in not just to build the rounded corner, insted the full layout.

Answer (score 1):

Only possible way to do this in pure CSS is by faking it with pseudo-elements:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: darkorange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
  border: 20px solid #FFF58F;
  border-top: 0
}

.circle::before, .circle::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFF58F;
}

.circle::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: -8px;
}

.circle::after {
  right: -20px;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```